# How do I hide a field given a checked box?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a dynamic query page. I am more than happy to learn ruby on rails which is what I am currently doing. However there is a time constraint for this and I have been searching high and low on how to hide a field on a form if a checkbox is checked. I have next to nothing ruby skills and I cant change to another language. Any assistance  would be greatly GREATLY appreciated. Also if you know a good tutorial for doing query pages would help!!!

Comment: Why is there a time constraint if you don't know how to do it? Dynamically hiding a field is a JavaScript action, not Rails or Ruby. I'd recommend looking into jQuery; Its tutorials cover this nicely so try starting with http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/ and http://learn.jquery.com/effects/intro-to-effects/.

Comment: its an internship and it end in a couple days and I just got the task, trying my best to ramp up quickly for the task, THANK YOU for the help!!!

Comment: @NickVeys is the one whose answer ([see below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20503792/128421)) will put you on the fast path. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For a form like:

```
<form ...>
  <input id="hide-box" type="checkbox" />
  <input id="field-to-hide" />
</form>
```

You'll need to use something like JQuery to listen for checking and hide accordingly.

```
$('#hide-box').on('change', function() {
  $('#field-to-hide').toggle($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```